# compile c++ program using g++ in windows command prompt

Tags: c++, cmd, g++

Why do I always have to go the directory where I have my c++ program saved. Can't I give its path as some argument or something and compile the program from anywhere in command prompt? Is there any such functionality available?

Comment: `g++ C:\some\path\to\file.cpp`?

Comment: There is, supply the full path, use a batch file or IDE or even better, use a build system.

Comment: What command line are you using? Do you just have one source file? Several?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude wow thank you so much.

Comment: @doctorlove yeah I had one source file. It worked though. Thank you.

Comment: I was already having 1 reputation less than required for chatting in chat.stackoverflow. Now 2 downvotes brought me down to 15 :O. Is this kind of question not allowed?

Comment: Such questions are not recommended (and you could have googled it). Try to answer existing questions to improve your score. Most SO questions want some [MCVE]

Comment: oh I will remember this in my future posts. Its time to contribute to SO. I need at least 20 reputation. I wish everyone was like you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single source (actually single translation unit) file, you could compile it with a command like:

```
g++ -Wall -g C:\some\path\to\file.cpp -o C:\other\path\to\executable\prog.exe
```

You want all warnings `-Wall` and debug info `-g` and you specify the generated executable with `-o`. Read more about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).

(I don't know Windows, but you might use `/` instead of `\` ....)

For a program with several translation units, I strongly recommend a script, or better yet, using some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/).

Generally, you can configure your [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) (sometimes called an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)) to run your preferred compilation or build command, perhaps with a single keypress. How to do that depends upon your editor (or IDE).

Don't forget to use some version control system. I strongly recommend [git](http://git-scm.com/).

Don't forget to learn how to [use the debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/).

BTW, Linux is often more developer-friendly than Windows, so you might consider installing some [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution).

Look also into existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) projects for inspiration (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/), [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/), etc...)

Comment: oh it works like charm. Also, thank you for that output file part. I was confused as although my program was running I couldn't see the change reflected in output file. So ignorant of me, I didn't think I must put the path to with .exe file as well.

Comment: PS: '\' works in windows.

Comment: But `/` should also work, and is more traditional (and Unix-compatible). On my French keyboard, it is easier to type than `\\`

Comment: oh okay. Thank you

Comment: BTW, you really should consider switching to Linux.... It is so much more developer-friendly

Comment: yeah I agree. I have that installed in a virtual environment as well. Its just the interface of windows which tempts me for usual day-to-day work.

Comment: Linux provides you with many different GUI interfaces, and they are highly configurable. Choose the one suiting your tastes.

Comment: I will switch to linux. It might get little bit amount of time to get used to it. But seems like its worth it. (it must be as a person with 157k recommends it). Thank you so much.

Comment: Notice that I am severely biased. I start coding in 1974 (at that time on punched cards) and I never used Windows.

Comment: Still I may easily trust your biases. 44 years is a great amount of time. wow.

Comment: @nerd - Before reformatting your hard drive, you could also shortly consider that [a user with a million rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) uses C# on .NET.  :-)

Comment: @BoPersson But Linux is recommended by many experienced programmers.

Comment: @nerd - Sure. But as a Windows user since 1.0 beta, I can not resist pointing out that using Linux is not a *unanimous* decision. And I don't particularly like running the compiler from a command line either, so the preferred development environment is obviously a matter of taste. Your choice!

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to go always to the same directory,you can give command from anywhere to execute..the other way you can do is :
    /folderpath && gcc 1.c   //for compiling
    or /folderpath && ./a.out  //for executing